# Why can't use realloc function to resize the stack which is of dynamic array?

Tags: c, arrays, stack, adt

The book tells me that I should declare a new, larger array (malloc) and copy the data from the old array to the new array to resize the stack.

But why can't I use realloc to adjust the size of the stack's length?

Comment: Are we talking about some stack data structure of yours or of the actual program stack? Could you show some code?

Comment: realloc should work, for such kind of tasks.

Comment: 《Pointers on C》@MichaelWalz

Comment: Just a simplest stack.@MatteoItalia

Comment: Maybe the author didn't know about `realloc`

Comment: He knows,because he writes it in the previous chapter@MattMcNabb

Comment: When you say `to resize the stack`, do you mean resize a **statically declared array** (stored on the stack). For example `int myarray[50];` then you need more space and the author suggests `int *myarray2 = malloc (100 * sizeof *myarray2);` then `memcpy (myarray2, myarray, 50 * sizeof *myarray2);` If the original was **statically declared**, then you cannot use `realloc` and must use `malloc` to create a new array and copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody stops you from using realloc. Moreover realloc is preferable. Without looking at context of material, I can not tell the intention of author why does he want to use malloc.